# Upload FPDF object to AWS S3 in Python

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, amazon-s3

I have FPDF object like this below:

```
import fpdf

pdf = FPDF()

#Cover page
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 16)
pdf.cell(175, 10, 'TEST - report',0,1,'C')
```

And I try to save this FPDF object to my S3 bucket inside AWS. I am using jupyter notebook on EMR.
When I run this:

```
my_bucket = 'my-bucket-name'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
dir = 'my-dir-name'
file = dir + 'test.pdf'
s3.Bucket(my_bucket).put_object(Key=file, Body=pdf)
```

I got error:

```
ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: <fpdf.fpdf.FPDF object at 0x7f2dfc2acd10>, type: <class 'fpdf.fpdf.FPDF'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object
```

Do you know how to handle it?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass pdf content bytes as the `Body` param

python2

```py
dir = 'my-dir-name'
file = 'test.pdf'
s3.Bucket(my_bucket).put_object(Key=dir+'/'+file, Body=pdf.output(file, 'S'))
```

python3

```py
dir = 'my-dir-name'
file = 'test.pdf'
s3.Bucket(my_bucket).put_object(Key=dir+'/'+file, Body=pdf.output(file, 'S').encode('latin-1'))
```

> NOTICE: In Python 2 strings were raw data but in Python 3 strings are
> now unicode by default. If you are using Python 3.x you have to use
> pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1') in order to get the output, if
> you don't do so the generated PDF will be invalid and depending on the
> viewer either not open at all or show up as some blank pages

document: [pdf.output()](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html)

Comment: It was very helpful, thank you. The PDF saves, but does not show the content defined in the cell, here: "TEST - report". Just empty file. Do you guess what could be the reason for this?

Comment: i have updated my answer, there's a litte issue with python3